# display single row for a date range in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is the table and data for experiment.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admission
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT serial,
    ad_date timestamp without time zone,
    company integer,
    CONSTRAINT admission_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
INSERT INTO admission (ad_date,company_id) VALUES
     ('2014-03-03 20:46:33',1),
     ('2014-03-03 20:49:13',1),
     ('2014-03-03 21:01:03',1),
     ('2014-03-03 21:01:06',1),
     ('2014-03-03 21:02:16',1),
     ('2014-03-03 21:02:22',1),
     ('2014-03-03 21:15:48',1),
     ('2014-03-03 21:16:19',1);
```

I need  admissions for the company occurred before every 15 min.

e.g below expected output

```
start_date                   next_15_min_date             total_count   company 
2014-03-03 20:46:33.000     2014-03-03 21:01:06.000           4            1
2014-03-03 21:02:16.000     2014-03-03 21:16:19.000           4            1
```

I tried

```
select t1.ad_date as start_date ,t2.ad_date as next_15_min_date , count(t2.ad_date),t2.company 
from admission t1,admission t2
where t2.ad_date between  t1.ad_date and t1.ad_date+interval '15 minute'
group by t1.ad_date,t2.ad_date,t2.company
order by t1.ad_date,t2.ad_date,t2.company
```

but its not working. Anybody knows?

Thanks

Comment: I've removed the sql-server tag from your question because the code you've posted here will not work on SQL Server.

Comment: @Avinash Which DB and version you are using ?
Your create table statement would throw error in `postgres 9.6`, `postgres 10`, `postgres 15`

Comment: postgres  version 15.1. I copied it from generated sql.

Answer (score 1):

What makes your query difficult is to detect what record must be used as the start of each range and what records fall in the middle of a range. The solution for that is a `generate_series` because it only needs to be passed a starting point in time (an end point too but it is not the important one here) to generate all the ranges you need.

BTW, I am writing 2 solutions that handle the gaps in data differently. No difference on the data set you have provided but if you add `('2014-03-03 21:43:19', 1), ('2014-03-03 21:48:00', 1)` to your test data, you will see the difference.

I added 2 helper columns (in comments) to make the difference more obvious. Feel free to uncomment them.

To be completely safe with `<=` vs. `<` and `>=` vs. `>`, I use ranges and the `<@` operator in the below queries.

**Solution 1**: 15-minute ranges starting from the first timestamp, with no reset (1 call to `generate_series` to get all the timestamp ranges).

```
WITH T(start_date, company) AS (
    SELECT generate_series (MIN(ad_date), MAX(ad_date), interval '15 minute'), company
    FROM admission
    GROUP BY company
) 
SELECT MIN(a.ad_date), MAX(a.ad_date), count(*), a.company
/*, t.start_date as start_date_range, t.start_date + interval '15 minute' as end_date_range*/
FROM admission a
JOIN T ON a.company = t.company and a.ad_date <@ tsrange(t.start_date, t.start_date + interval '15 minute', '[)')
GROUP BY a.company, t.start_date
```

**Solution 2**: 15-minute ranges, resetting every time a gap is detected (potentially several calls to `generate_series` if gaps are detected by the `NOT EXISTS`):

```
WITH T(start_date, company) AS (
    SELECT generate_series(ad_date, LEAD(ad_date - interval '15 minute', 1 , ad_date + interval '15 minute') OVER w, interval '15 minute'), company
    FROM admission a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
        FROM admission
        WHERE (ad_date < a.ad_date AND ad_date + interval '15 minute' >= a.ad_date)
    )
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY ad_date)
) 
SELECT MIN(a.ad_date), MAX(a.ad_date), count(*), a.company
/*, t.start_date as start_date_range, t.start_date + interval '15 minute' end_date_range*/
FROM admission a
JOIN T ON a.company = t.company and a.ad_date <@ tsrange(t.start_date, t.start_date + interval '15 minute', '[)')
GROUP BY a.company, t.start_date
```

---

Note: based on your sample data, that is not what you are asking for but to be complete, I must say I would personnally group the timestamps so that ranges start `0`, `15`, `30` and `45` minutes after each hour.
This is achieved very easily by casting `MIN(ad_date)` to type `date` in Solution 1, which moves all the subsequent ranges.

```
WITH T(start_date, company) AS (
    SELECT generate_series (MIN(ad_date)::date, MAX(ad_date), interval '15 minute'), company
    FROM admission
    GROUP BY company
) 
SELECT MIN(a.ad_date), MAX(a.ad_date), count(*), a.company
/*, t.start_date as start_date_range, t.start_date + interval '15 minute' as end_date_range*/
FROM admission a
JOIN T ON a.company = t.company and a.ad_date <@ tsrange(t.start_date, t.start_date + interval '15 minute', '[)')
GROUP BY a.company, t.start_date
```

Comment: Hey Thanks@Atmo. This is close to solution